# Failed to register dll files needed for DTS - Error -The specified module could not be found

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dts

I am trying to register a DLL file needed for DTS using this command

```
Regsvr32.exe "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\COM\axscphst.dll"
```

But I get the error

```
RegSvr32
---------------------------
LoadLibrary("C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\COM\axscphst.dll") failed - The specified module could not be found.
```

But Iam sure that the file axscphst.dll present in that location.

Can anyone tell me what I should do to find why its not getting registered only on this PC. If there is any workaround, kindly let me know that too.  Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the DLL with Dependency Walker (depends.exe, 
http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on the machine where registration 
fails. Most likely, your DLL depends on some libraries not present on 
the machine - Depends will tell you which.

Comment: Thanks Vikaram..I checked for dependencies using "Depends" that comes with Visual Basic 6.. Found that one of the references were missing.. References were missing because the Environment variables Path were not correct.. Corrected the Env Variable path and everything is working fine now .